# Número único en Oracle

Tags: oracle-19c

Necesito obtener un número único de la instalación de Oracle, he investigado y lo más cercano que he encontrado ha sido DBID que se genera al crear la BD, pero no he encontrado su algoritmo por lo que no estoy segura de que este número en otras instalaciones de Oracle no se llegue a repetir, por lo que la solución en la que he pensado es generar un número con base a otros datos de la instancia, pero no sé cuales podría utilizar, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Ese identificador es único para la instancia y la BD lo pone en los encabezados a todos los archivos relacionados. Nada en su generación busca sincronizarlo con un catálogo global ni tiene cómo saber qué ID está disponible en el mundo (y como lo dices, no está predefinido como las direcciones MAC, por ejemplo).

Comment: Por eso entiendo que puede llegarse a repetir, y lo que necesito es un número irrepetible pero no sé que datos utilizar

Comment: Irrepetible en todas las instancias del mundo? No lo hay. Podría uno jugar a generar hashes con datos de configuración, datos del servidor... generar un fingerprint

Comment: Quería generarlo obteniendo los datos del servidor, utilice el comando HOST pero no puedo manipular los datos que me devuelve y es que es numero único lo necesito generar a través de una consulta